# Create multiple file from single txt file

Tags: linux, shell-script, text, replication

I have a single input file that needs to be replicated multiple times with a little change in every file i.e every 30th line in every file is to change.

For e.g.

My main text file name is D0.txt which I need to replicate multiple numbers time. and in that line 30 is "variable D1 equal 0.0 "

Now for the first time when I replicate this file

I would like to change that string to " variable D1 equal 1 "

and then save the file as D1.txt.

Similarly, I would like to create suppose 5 files then I would like to loop it 100 times.

so files are saved in a folder as

D0.txt

D1.txt

D2.txt and so on with each of their line 30 as "Diameter = $n"
sample text file format is attached below.
and desired format of files in folder.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash you can do

```
for i in {1..5}; do
 cp D0.txt D$i.txt;
 sed -i "30s/.*/variable D1 equal $i/" D$i.txt;
done
```

Here `{1..5}` specify the range of the loop and during each iteration we are

Making copy of file with new Name.
Using sed command to replace the text on line 30. where `-i` specify in-place ,`30` specify line number, `s` specify to serch the given text in our case it is `.*` which states any text on line 30 and we want to replace  that text with `variable D1 equal $i` to the file `D$i.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, @Vaibhav.c Solution provided works perfectly. It would save me a lot of time. Thanks again for taking out time to solve it.